# Wordpress CSS Bootstrap how to show more columns in Masonry Grid Layout

Tags: android, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I know little about CSS, much less about Bootstrap framework. 
In the main page, my theme (Jax) shows 3 post previews columns by default. It is responsive and shows only one of them when the current device is a mobile phone, for example.

With only 3 columns, it still remains a lot of unused space, so to set it to 4 columns I change this in css:

```
.col-md-4 {
    width: 25%; /*(instead of 33,33%)*/
  }
```

It works in desktop pc and laptop, but now, in mobile devices, it has become completely unformatted, showing a letter by row in one column, like this:

[image]

Edit: in theme's css file. I've noticed it doesn't use .col-xs, sm or lg classes, onlye .col-md-* classes. I don't know what code section I have to show to you, I'm modifying bootstrap.css code percentages, but I know the problem is in theme template css.

Comment: Please post a complete, working example of your code (static HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: for mobile you need to use `col-xs-*` in your html.